# Как импортировать модели EntityFramework из либы?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, entity-framework

Написал библиотеку, в ней схема данных, созданная Entity Framework со всеми классами сущностей и пр. Делаю проект приложения, подключаю к нему эту либу, хочу юзать эту схему данных, причем применительно к конкретной базе, заданной в приложении. Как это сделать? И чтобы все таблицы, которые предусмотрены этой схемой, нарисовались в базе автоматически.

Answer (score 2):

Вызовите `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer` для контекста выдернутой из сборки модели. Она создаст базу данных.

После этого можете пересоздать модель у себя и добавлять туда сущности, какие хотите.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework либо создает базу целиком, либо, подключаясь к существующей, не делает в ней ничего. Чтобы в **конкретной базе** создались новые объекты, Вам придется их добавлять вручную.